# Is the death penalty for Talos IV real or was it something the Talosians want others to believe?

Tags: star-trek

It has been discussed in scifi that there is no range limitation effective on the illusions the Talosians can force upon conscious beings and it was observed how easy therefore it would be to make a crew member accidentally destroy the ship (even if this required multiple crew members to accidentally collaborate in this - Talosians are very, very intelligent).

So what is the point of having any penalty associated with visiting Talos IV -- perhaps such visits occur often when the inhabitants have a desire to read minds "close up" if that is even a thing: the Talosians may have no need to have physical visits and there sole motivation in bringing the injured Pike to Talos IV was a combination of altruism that only a Talosian can carry out and perhaps their own interest in living through humans who ***want*** to participate in the illusion.

If the Talosian illusions are as powerful as indicated, the Federation would want to be on good terms with that species and even send other helpless cases to Talos.

Comment: Bringing yourself to the attention of nearly omnipotent beings is a very bad idea. Doing so nearly got the entire human (and Klingon) race banished to its own star system not once but twice.

Comment: Powerful species like this never get involved in "mortal" affairs." Q probably could have ended the Dominion War with the snap of a finger but never got involved.

Comment: I believe [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100595/why-was-there-a-death-penalty-for-going-to-talos-iv?rq=1) answers your question and the next one you asked.

Comment: If you question something that basic you could with equal justification contemplate every episode after the Cage is an illusion to convince Spock and crew they had further adventures farther from Talos IV.

Comment: It seems like, your argument points rather the opposite way - the Talosians would have no difficulty keeping unwanted visitors away from their planet, why would they resort to something convoluted like faking there being a Starfleet regulation forbidding it?